# Extjs Grid doesn't show any data

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridpanel

I created the following grid component:

```
MyApp.grids.RelationshipMemberGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
    autoHeight: true,
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    title: 'Relationship Members',
    frame: true,
    viewConfig: { forceFit: true },
    relationshipId: null,
    documentId: null,

    initComponent: function () {
        if (this.verifyParameters()) {
            // Initiate functionality
            this.columns = this.buildColumns();
            this.view = this.buildView();
            this.store = this.buildStore();
            this.store.load();
        }

        MyApp.grids.RelationshipMemberGrid.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    },

    verifyParameters: function () {
        // Verification code
    },

    buildColumns: function () {
        return [{
            header: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'Id',
            sortable: true,
            width: 10
        }, {
            header: 'Type',
            dataIndex: 'ObjType',
            sortable: true,
            width: 10
        }, {
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'Name',
            sortable: true
        }];
    },

    buildView: function () {
        return new Ext.grid.GroupingView({
            forceFit: true,
            groupTextTpl: '{text} ({[values.rs.length]} {[values.rs.length > 1 ? "Members" : "Member"]})'
        });
    },

    buildStore: function () {
        return new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
            url: MyAppUrls.ListRelationshipMembers,
            baseParams: { relationshipId: this.relationshipId },
            root: 'data',
            fields: ['Id', 'ObjType', 'Name'],
            sortInfo: { field: 'Name', direction: 'ASC' },
            groupField: 'ObjType'
        });
    }
});
```

The grid renders correctly, and the URL that is mapped to `MyAppUrls.ListRelationshipMembers` is correct.  The data is being retrieved, and the `ListRelationshipMembers` URL is returning the following JSON:

```
{"data":[{"Id":1,"ObjType":"topic","Name":"Test2"}]}
```

Yet, even though the grid is rendered (columns, borders, etc..) no data is showing in the actual grid though.  Since this is my first time using a data store, I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be appreciative.

***Edit***:

I tried updating the store to have a reader via the following code:

```
    return new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
        url: MyAppUrls.ListRelationshipMembers,
        baseParams: { relationshipId: this.relationshipId },
        fields: ['Id', 'ObjType', 'Name'],
        sortInfo: { field: 'Name', direction: 'ASC' },
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            root: 'data' 
        }),
        groupField: 'ObjType'
    });
```

No change, the datagrid is not being filled with the records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evan is correct. Your biggest problem is a lack of a reader. That and the validation stub you left in there needed to return true. If you can't just drop this code in and have it work you have some other problem.

```
MyApp.grids.RelationshipMemberGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
    autoHeight: true,
    iconCls: 'icon-grid',
    title: 'Relationship Members',
    frame: true,
    viewConfig: { forceFit: true },
    relationshipId: null,
    documentId: null,

        initComponent: function () {
        if (this.verifyParameters()) {
            // Initiate functionality
            this.columns = this.buildColumns();
            this.view = this.buildView();
            this.store = this.buildStore();
            this.store.load();
        }

        MyApp.grids.RelationshipMemberGrid.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    },

    verifyParameters: function () {
        // Verification code
        return true;
    },

    buildColumns: function () {
        return [{
            header: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'Id',
            sortable: true,
            width: 10
        }, {
            header: 'Type',
            dataIndex: 'ObjType',
            sortable: true,
            width: 10
        }, {
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'Name',
            sortable: true
        }];
    },

    buildView: function () {
        return new Ext.grid.GroupingView({
            forceFit: true,
            groupTextTpl: '{text} ({[values.rs.length]} {[values.rs.length > 1 ? "Members" : "Member"]})'
        });
    },

    buildStore: function () {
        return new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
            url: MyAppUrls.ListRelationshipMembers,
            baseParams: { relationshipId: this.relationshipId },
            reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                root: 'data',
                fields: ['Id', 'ObjType', 'Name'],
                sortInfo: { field: 'Name', direction: 'ASC' },
                groupField: 'ObjType'
            })
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked.  Turns out my issue on the 2nd try was the fields array was in my GroupingStore when it should have been in the reader!

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to do a couple of things here: firstly, as mentioned by Evan, you need to add a reader to your store, like this:

```
buildStore: function () {
    return new Ext.data.Store({
        url: MyAppUrls.ListRelationshipMembers,
        baseParams: { relationshipId: this.relationshipId },
        fields: ['Id', 'ObjType', 'Name'],
        sortInfo: { field: 'Name', direction: 'ASC' },
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            root: 'data' 
        })
    });
}
```

I've changed the store type here to something simpler - was there a particular reason you were using GroupingStore? Note that the root is specified in the reader, not the store itself.

Then, in your columns, I'd tend to add a renderer to explicitly determine what each column will display, such as:

```
buildColumns: function () {
    return [{
        header: 'Id',
        dataIndex: 'Id',
        sortable: true,
        width: 10,
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
            return record.data.Id
        }
    } ... ];
}
```

I've got into the habit of using renderers, since I modify the content of my column cells quite heavily in my grids. Notice here the arguments being passed to the renderer function; there are a few more you can pass in - see the [ExtJS API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.Column) if you need more info on what you can actually access. On that note, the API documentation is pretty good - it can take some digging into but definitely worth your time if you're working with ExtJS a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll check some of these changes once I get home from work.  As to the grouping data store, I want my datagrid to group together the results based on `ObjType` for user friendliness.  I thought to use the GroupingStore due to the example here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grouping.html, as that closely mimics what I want to do.

Comment: Adding the JsonReader to the store did not load the data into the grid, nor did changing it from a `GroupingStore` to a `Store`.  My grid is still empty

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a reader on your store, you need to specify the root in the JsonReader.

Comment: Adding a JsonReader to the store did not add the data to the grid